# inter-group (between groups) combination of column A grouped by column B

Tags: r, combinations

I think this is a graphical theory question: how many lines can we draw between two sets of points... which i'm not familiar with...

for example

```
df = data.frame(city = c('Boston', 'Cambridge', 'Long Island', 'NYC'),
                state = c('MA', 'MA', 'NY', 'NY'))

         city state
1      Boston    MA
2   Cambridge    MA
3 Long Island    NY
4         NYC    NY
```

Cities are spitted / grouped by state. How to get

```
Boston - Long Island
Boston - NYC
Cambridge - Long Island
Cambridge - NYC
```

In other words, I want to generate every city pair where the two cities are in different states.

A more general example:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(value = 1:100,
                group = letters[sample(1:26, 100, replace=T)])

> df
    value group
1       1     e
2       2     m
3       3     g
4       4     o
5       5     p
6       6     a
7       7     i
8       8     o
9       9     i
10     10     h
11     11     p
12     12     h
...    ...    ...
```

I want all combination (value1, value2) or equivalently (index1, index2) where value1 and value2 has different group labels.

Comment: You want to create a network?

Comment: hi thanks @Pascal i'm not sure about the definition of network, but yeah it sounds like a network: play a match with anyone except those in your own team

Comment: why Tim's answer disappeared...:(

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen it seems like I don't... your answer's cool - the $A$A, $A$B thing is useful here and in other cases too. Could you put it here how did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

For loop, although discouraged in R, can be used to get desired result:

```
ddf = data.frame(value = 1:20,  group = letters[sample(1:3, 20, replace=T)])
head(ddf)
  value group
1     1     b
2     2     b
3     3     b
4     4     c
5     5     a
6     6     a

for(i in 1:20){
    tempdf = ddf[ddf$group!=ddf[i,2],]
    cat(ddf[i,1],': ',tempdf[,1], '\n')
}

1 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
2 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
3 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
4 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19 
5 :  1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 20 
6 :  1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 20 
7 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
8 :  1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 20 
9 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19 
10 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19 
11 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
12 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
13 :  1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 20 
14 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
15 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19 
16 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
17 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19 
18 :  4 5 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 19 20 
19 :  1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 20 
20 :  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 16 18 19
```

Each pair can be listed:

```
for(i in 1:20){
    tempdf = ddf[ddf$group!=ddf[i,2],]
    for(j in 1:nrow(tempdf)){
        cat(ddf[i,1], tempdf[j,1], '\n') 
    }
}

}
1 4 
1 5 
1 6 
1 8 
1 9 
1 10 
1 13 
1 15 
1 17 
1 19 
1 20 
2 4 
2 5 
2 6 
2 8 
2 9 
2 10 
2 13 
2 15 
2 17 
....
```

The pairs can easily be obtained in another data.frame.

To create another data.frame:

```
outdf = data.frame(first=numeric(), second=numeric())

for(i in 1:20){
    tempdf = ddf[ddf$group!=ddf[i,2],]
    for(j in 1:nrow(tempdf)){
        outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = c(ddf[i,1], tempdf[j,1])
    }
}
head(outdf)
  first second
1     1      3
2     1      4
3     1      5
4     1      7
5     1      8
6     1      9
```

To remove duplicates, first sort each pair:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(outdf)){
    if(outdf[i,2] < outdf[i,1])
        outdf[i,] = c(outdf[i,2], outdf[i,1])
}
outdf
```

For sorting each row, following R code may be preferred:

```
outdf = data.frame(t(apply(outdf, 1, sort)))
```

Then remove duplicates:

```
outdf = outdf[!duplicated(outdf),]
```

Number of unique pairs will be:

```
nrow(outdf)
```

Comment: modified your answer to avoid duplicate pairs :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @mso answer, if you:

1. just want to count the number of possible pairs
2. a->b is same as b->a (undirected graph).

   ```
   > set.seed(123)
   > n<-10 # number of value
   > k<-3  # number of groups
   > df = data.frame(value = 1:n,  group = letters[sample(1:k, n, replace=T)])
   > df
      value group
   1      1     a
   2      2     c
   3      3     b
   4      4     c
   5      5     c
   6      6     a
   7      7     b
   8      8     c
   9      9     b
   10    10     b

   > tbl<-table(df$group) # Tabulate number within each group
   > tbl
   a b c
   2 4 4
   > sum(outer(tbl,tbl)[upper.tri(outer(tbl,tbl))]) # Count number of pairs
   [1] 32
   > sum(apply(combn(1:length(tbl),2),2,function(x) prod(tbl[x]) )) # Another way
   [1] 32

   >for(i in 1:n){
     tempdf = df[df$group!=df[i,2] & c(rep(F,i),rep(T,n-i)),]
     cat(df[i,1],': ',tempdf[,1], '\n')
   }

   1 :  2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10
   2 :  3 6 7 9 10
   3 :  4 5 6 8
   4 :  6 7 9 10
   5 :  6 7 9 10
   6 :  7 8 9 10
   7 :  8
   8 :  9 10
   9 :
   10 :

   >count<-0
   >for(i in 1:n){
     tempdf = df[df$group!=df[i,2] & c(rep(F,i),rep(T,n-i)),]
     if (nrow(tempdf)>0){
       for(j in 1:nrow(tempdf)){
         cat(df[i,1], tempdf[j,1], '\n')
         count<-count+1
       }
     }
   }

    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 5
    1 7
    1 8
   ...

   > count
   [1] 32
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross_join

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(city = c('Boston', 'Cambridge', 'Long Island', 'NYC'),
                state = c('MA', 'MA', 'NY', 'NY'))

prefix = function(df, prefix)
  df %>%
  setNames(names(.) %>%
             paste(prefix, ., sep = "_") )

df %>% prefix("from") %>%
  merge(df %>% prefix("to")) %>%
  filter(!(from_city == to_city & from_state == to_state))
```

Comment: This doesn't filter out duplicate pairs.  E.g. your results have `NYC - Boston` _and_ `Boston - NYC`.  This is not what the OP wants, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

For your quesiton, if we have k groups with m1, m2, ..., mk components, then the total number of unique pairs between different groups is:

(m1*m2 + m1*m3 +...+ m1*mk)+(m2*m3+m2*m4+...+m2*mk)+...+(m(k-1)*mk)

I have a solution:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(city = 1:10,
state = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4),rep(3,3)))

res=NULL
df[,{tt=combn(.SD[,city],2)
res<<-cbind(res,tt)},by=state]

res.all <- combn(df[,city],2)
res <- paste(res[1,],res[2,])
res.all <- paste(res.all[1,],res.all[2,])
res.all[!(res.all %in% res)]

> df
city state
 1:    1     1
 2:    2     1
 3:    3     1
 4:    4     2
 5:    5     2
 6:    6     2
 7:    7     2
 8:    8     3
 9:    9     3
10:   10     3
> as.matrix(res.all[!(res.all %in% res)])
      [,1]  
 [1,] "1 4" 
 [2,] "1 5" 
 [3,] "1 6" 
 [4,] "1 7" 
 [5,] "1 8" 
 [6,] "1 9" 
 [7,] "1 10"
 [8,] "2 4" 
 [9,] "2 5" 
[10,] "2 6" 
[11,] "2 7" 
[12,] "2 8" 
[13,] "2 9" 
[14,] "2 10"
[15,] "3 4" 
[16,] "3 5" 
[17,] "3 6" 
[18,] "3 7" 
[19,] "3 8" 
[20,] "3 9" 
[21,] "3 10"
[22,] "4 8" 
[23,] "4 9" 
[24,] "4 10"
[25,] "5 8" 
[26,] "5 9" 
[27,] "5 10"
[28,] "6 8" 
[29,] "6 9" 
[30,] "6 10"
[31,] "7 8" 
[32,] "7 9"
[33,] "7 10"
```