# How to reformat data.frame based on value combinations?

Tags: r

I have a list of ID-product combinations that I would like to manipulate in R.  I would like to a list of all product combinations based on the matching ID.  If an ID included a product with no other products (in other words, a single row ID), then the secondary product would be "n/a."

For instance:

```
user <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4)
prod <- c(100,120,140,100,110,120,150)
data <- cbind(user, prod)

data
      user prod
[1,]   1   100
[2,]   1   120
[3,]   2   140
[4,]   3   100
[5,]   4   110
[6,]   4   120
[7,]   4   150
```

Would be converted to this:

```
Primary Secondary
100     120
120     100
110     120
110     150
120     110
120     150
150     110
150     120
140     n/a
100     n/a
```

I read up on reshape and the apply functions, but I'm not sure how to apply them to this task.

Comment: This problem is very similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382046/inter-group-between-groups-combination-of-column-a-grouped-by-column-b/). try modifying the answers to suit your problem (toi within-group instead of between-group).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[, if(.N > 1) 
         CJ(Primary=prod, Secondary=prod)[
           Primary != Secondary][
           order(Primary)] 
       else list(Primary=prod, Secondary=as.double(NA)), by=user]

#     user Primary Secondary
#  1:    1     100       120
#  2:    1     120       100
#  3:    2     140        NA
#  4:    3     100        NA
#  5:    4     110       120
#  6:    4     110       150
#  7:    4     120       110
#  8:    4     120       150
#  9:    4     150       110
# 10:    4     150       120
```

If `user` has more than one row, return the combinations of `prod`, through `CJ()`, other just `prod` and `NA`.

Comment: I was thinking something similar but what the point of using `data.table` if you are using `expend.grid` instead of just `CJ`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg You're right, thanks! `CJ` used to be slower, but no longer. I updated my answer.